# string containing comma delimited values to an ARRAY

Tags: type-conversion

Looking at the following code snippet :

```
    public JsonResult GetMapList(string siteDescription,string siteStatus)
    {
        var IDs = new[] { 3,4,5 };
```

Can anyone please advise me on the neatest way to replace the hardcoded 3,4,5 part with the variable siteStatus that will contain a dynamic comma separated string like 3,4,5

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might need to do a null check around this

```
string[] values = siteStatus.Split(',');

int[] ids =  Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(values, delegate(string s) { return int.Parse(s); });
```

or with LINQ

```
var ints = from m in siteStatus.Split(',')
           select Convert.ToInt32(m);
```

Comment: That would make IDs an array of strings.

Comment: I think you'll find that the question asked for a dynamic comma separated STRING

Comment: thanks, This almost works, it says 'try specifying the type arguments explicitly'. Can your declaration be set to be int?

Comment: Sorry guys I should have explained, i'm then using this value in a LINQ statement, looks like : "where IDs.Contains(s.SiteStatusId)" and i think it must be int to work

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.WebPages;

var IDs = siteStatus.Split(',').Select(n => n.AsInt());
```

or (probably you'll need also a validation, because this will break on wrong input)

```
var IDs = siteStatus.Split(',').Select(n => int.Parse(n));
```